# Ethereum hd wallets making transactions like bitcoin wallets

Tags: bitcoin, hd-wallets

I'm working on an exchange where every user has given a unique address, generated via ethereum hd wallets. How can i use a single master private key to transfer available funds from different generated addresses like we do with bitcoin wallets where we can select multiple addresses with different balances in a single transaction?

Comment: Check out my answer about doing the same thing with [Token contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64686/collecting-erc20-balances-from-multiple-addresses/64689#64689)

Comment: Ethereum transactions have a single sender, you cannot gather several "inputs" like in Bitcoin.