# Is minting gas through gastoken.io still efficient to reduce Ethereum gas costs?

Tags: transactions, tokens, ether, gas

[A SE user](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64689/65596) suggested using https://gastoken.io to mint gas when fees are low in order to save on gas when fees are high. However, I'm wondering if there's any benefit of doing this today.

According to the [GasToken Calculator](https://gastoken.io/#calculator) if you mint gas when gas price is equal to 1 Gwei and free gas when gas price is equal to 50 Gwei (50 x) you'd get an approx. 300% reduction in the cost of gas. However, if the difference between minting time vs freeing time is less than 5x you're looking at a return of only 50%. When analyzing gas price [over the past 1000 blocks](https://etherscan.io/gastracker) it doesn't look like the fees ever fell even close to 5x to make the effort vs, reward worthwhile.

So my question is: Is this strategy still effective?

Comment: I believe you already answered yourself.

Comment: I have the same question. Could you please reply if you have found the answer?